# MySQL - Filter rows that have the exact same decimal values in two colums

Tags: mysql

[image: Table]

This is a picture of the tablestructure I want to filter. To know if there is congruent-data in the table I try to get all rows with the exact same joblat and joblng values.

Can please someone give me a hint or an answer how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE joblat=joblng; < this?

Comment: I need to compare it to other rows. - I want to see if there are multiple rows with the exact same joblat and joblng numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find such rows using `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS x
    WHERE x.pk <> t.pk -- replace this actual primary key column
    AND x.joblat = t.joblat
    AND x.joblng = t.joblng
)
```

Comment: Hi Salman, thank you.. this works! But when I use it, i only get pairs with the same values back. Now, I dont, know if its because of the data in my table, or because of the query. Should this query give me also three or more rows back, if they have the same lat, lng value? The "SELECT 1" statement makes me curious

Comment: It'll give you all rows that have at least one duplicate... the row and _all copies_ of it. If you want just the main row you need to decide a criteria (e.g. the row with smallest pk is considered main and all others are considered copies) then adjust the query. Replacing `<>` with `>` should do this. If you want to select all copies then it is little tricky.

Comment: There is no real "main row", so - I want all rows which have congruent data in the joblat and joblng field.

Comment: Then it should be returning all such rows.